# Accepting audio file in api

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core

I am trying to convert my API to accept an audio file instead of a string but after looking into it I can not find a suitable example on how to do so.

At the moment the Speech-To-Text service is run locally but I want to move this to the server. The API call to the wit.ai services I already made. The thing left is to make the API accept a audio file(audio will always be .wav)

If anyone has some suggestions let me know I am stuck on this

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api")]
public class CommandApiController : Controller
{
    // constructor

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessCommandAsync([FromBody]string command)
    {
        // Testing SpeechToText method
        string path = @"C:\Users\rickk\Desktop\SmartSpeaker\agenda.wav";
        // Overridden for now  
        command = await CovnvertSpeechToTextApiCall(new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)));

        // Logic

    }


    async Task<string> CovnvertSpeechToTextApiCall(ByteArrayContent content)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/wav");

        // Wit.ai server token
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.wit.ai/speech", content);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var modeldata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.DeserializedJsonDataModel>(response);

            return modeldata._text;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment.

Not exactly what I was looking for but that is my fault for not explaining it correctly. Here is what I have found as a solution.

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/audio")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessCommandAsync([FromForm]IFormFile command)
    {  
        if(command.ContentType != "audio/wav" && command.ContentType != "audio/wave" || command.Length < 1)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var text = await CovnvertSpeechToTextApiCall(ConvertToByteArrayContent(command));

        return Ok(FormulateResponse(text));
    }


    private ByteArrayContent ConvertToByteArrayContent(IFormFile audofile)
    {
        byte[] data;

        using (var br = new BinaryReader(audofile.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            data = br.ReadBytes((int) audofile.OpenReadStream().Length);
        }

        return new ByteArrayContent(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your thread. I have 2 questions:
1. I have the error "The type or namespace name 'Model' could not be found", is that Speech-To-Text model? If I want to replace this model with mine and call my API, what should I do?
2. How to pass ".wav" file to ProcessCommandAsync? I have an error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'"
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily upload a file into Asp.net core web api using IFormFile as following where you accept a parameter of the previous type inside your post action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAudioFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        /* 
         * the content types of Wav are many
         * audio/wave
         * audio/wav
         * audio/x-wav
         * audio/x-pn-wav
         * see "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types"
        */
        if (file.ContentType != "audio/wave")
        {
            return BadRequest("Wrong file type");
        }
        var uploads = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");//uploads where you want to save data inside wwwroot
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return Ok("File uploaded successfully");
    }
```

You will need to ask for IHostingEnvironment object in your controller constructor using dependency injection as following:

```
public FileController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
```

And then assign it to property inside your controller.

Beside that don't forget to send your request from the client as Multipart form as following (example):
[image: Client RESTFull API test]